# Retrofit 2 handle dynamic errors

Tags: android, error-handling, retrofit2

i am using retrofit 2 where i am sending request to a rest server. I am having issues with parsing the error resposne from the server. As an example i am showing the register api call.

One i hit this endpoint with a email which is not present in the server db i am getting the following reposne :

```
{
    "id": "90c51a63-9a5d-46ee-9da6-7227f7042373",
    "email": "tkosaev@abv.bg",
    "username": "TOdor",
    "phoneNumber": null,
    "phoneNumberIsVerified": false,
    "isIdenfyVerified": false
}
```

I am able to parse the above json to Java object. The issue comes if i want to catch the error like if i use the same email the backend returns a 400 status with message that the email already exist as there was already a user registered with that same email. Below you can find how the json looks, my question is how can i parse this reponse.

```
  {
      "Message": "One or more validation failures have occurred.",
      "Failures": {
          "Email": [
             "Email already exists."
          ]
       }
  }
```

PS: keep in mind that the email object can change based on different errors from the server. Is there a way to handle this elegantly.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

you can get error response by this `onResposne()`

```
try {
  JSONObject jObjError = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
  Log.e("Error ", "response : " + jObjError);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and you can check api status code by

`response.code()`

Comment: Is there a way to make this more generic like use a interceptor/deserilizer or TypeAdapterFactory ?

Comment: response.errorBody().string() return error response you can make it more generic according to your use.

Answer (score 0):

Create a model to handle your custom error

```
class CustomError {
    String Message;
    List<String> Failures;

    ...

    //getter and setter
}
```

Then using Retrofit `responseBodyConverter` parse your error model like below:

```
public CustomError getCustomError(ResponseBody responseBody) {
    CustomError customError;

    Converter converter = retrofit.responseBodyConverter(CustomError.class, new Annotation[] {});

    try {
        customError = (CustomError) converter.convert(responseBody);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        customError = null;
    }

    return customError;
}
```

And try to change your response like below to handle it dynamically

```
{
    "Message": "One or more validation failures have occurred.",
    "Failures": [
        "Email already exists.",
        "Invalid phone number",
        "Username not found"
    ]
}
```

Comment: @Boris, Did you check this?